# How do I stop counting duplicates of a particular value after its already counted once in an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

For example I have an array:

```
arr[9] = {1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 7}
```

I then sort the array to get

```
arr[9] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 9, 9}
```

Then I count duplicates for each value using two for loops. The output I want is:

```
2 instances of 2
3 instances of 9
```

Instead, I get:

```
2 instances of 2
3 instances of 9
2 instances of 9
```

I know that after the loop goes once, when **arr[6]**, the outer loop counts that there are **two more 9** but after that is finished, and loop goes to **arr[7]**, the outer loop still counts there is **another 9** which is **arr[8]**. So my question, how do I stop the code when it has counted duplicates for each number in the array **once**. Thanks!

Example code:

```
#define NUM = 9
int main() {
    arr[NUM] = {1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 7};
    sort_int_array(arr, NUM); //insertion sort function

    int i, j, count=1;
    for (i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
        for (j=i+1;j<NUM; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
            }
            if (arr[i] != arr[j] && count>1) {
                printf("%d instances of %d\n", count, arr[i]);
                count=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a minimal compl;ete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I will edit the post one minute.

Comment: @kaylum I gave an example code now.

Comment: @OffensiveBandit Why is this function sort_int_array(arr, NUM); called 9 times?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry my real code has 9 sets of 9 values of array, I just gave an example code but I forgot to remove the 9 times sort part lol. I'll delete that.

Comment: You need to post a [mre]. Make sure it is both minimal and reproducible.

Comment: "Then I count duplicates for each value using two for loops". That's what you are doing wrong. You only need to go over the sorted array once. You don't need to compare every element with every other element.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thank you so much brother, I found the mistake and fixed it.

Comment: OffensiveBandit, please create an answer.

Comment: Please state whether answers can assume the sorted array, because that makes things much easier. If on the other hand the sorted array is not given, there are probably answers without sorting which are altogether more efficient.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't how to solve this problem without sorting array so I am sorting to get the answers. And I posted the answer I got also. Thanks.

Comment: "I don't how to solve this problem without sorting array" OK. But do you want an answer based on sorting or would you accept/prefer an efficient answer without sorting?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer guys, thank you for helping. I just needed to remove the 2nd for loop.

```
#define NUM = 9
int main() {
    arr[NUM] = {1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 7};
    sort_int_array(arr, NUM); //insertion sort function

    int i, count=1;
    for (i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
            count++;
        }
        if (arr[i] != arr[i+1] && count>1) {
            printf("%d instances of %d\n", count, arr[i]);
            count=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, you are going over the array boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you go to the first nine, then it counts the next two. THEN it will go to the duplicate and also compare the duplicate against the other duplicate. I assume what you could do is check if arr[i] is not equal to arr[i - 1] so you don't compare duplicates

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two for loops for this, it would be inefficient and increases the complexity of the code.

If you are doing this with hand you would

1. Bring another sheet of paper.
2. for each number in the array:

   - if it's the first time you see this number:
     Note it down and record it has count of 1
   - else:
     then increment the count by 1

if you only need elements that occurred at least twice, you can filter out elements with count = 1.

As for the code:

```cpp
// this is called frequency array, which we will use to store the 
// number of occurrences (frequency) of a given number.
// The size of the array must be larger than the largest number in the array
int sz = 10  // sz = largest expected element + 1 (this only works for array of integers).
int freq[sz];

memset(freq, 0, sz * sizeof(int));  // reset all values in the array to 0

int arr[9] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 9, 9};
int i;

for (i = 0;i < 9;i++){
    cur = arr[i]; // read the current element
    freq[cur] += 1;  // increment its count by 1
}

for (i = 0;i < sz;i++) {
    count = freq[i];   // read the count of the number i
    if(count != 0) {
        // a count of 0 means that the number didn't occur in the array
        // you can also exclude numbers occurring only once by count > 1
        printf("%d instances of %d\n", count, i);
    }
}
```

I didn't test this code but this is the concept, you can find more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-frequency-number-array/).

This implementation uses more space than needed, but it has fast access time, if you move to cpp, you can use stl `map` or `unordered_map` for more space-efficient solution.

Comment: And what to do if not only single digits are used as values of array elements?

Comment: Moreover the question is marked as a C question not a C++ question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow For larger numbers, you need a larger array size, larger than the largest expected number in the sequence,  and as for the matter with cpp, there are only some changes in syntax, I'll add them now.

Comment: So the resume is your solution does not make a sense.:)

Comment: I'm simply trying to address the matter from algorithms point of view, even though it's inefficient in terms of space, it's widely used in competitive programming, and a good and simple topic for a newcomer.
With this approach he doesn't need to use sorting which takes more time, so my solution is simply trading space for time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how numbers of occurrences of elements of an array cam be calculated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    int x = *( const int * )a;
    int y = *( const int * )b;
    
    return ( y < x ) - ( x < y );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[] = {1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 7};
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );
    
    qsort( arr, N, sizeof( int ), cmp );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != N; )
    {
        size_t j = i;
        size_t count = 1;
        while ( ++i != N && arr[i] == arr[j] ) ++count;

        printf( "%zu instances of %d\n", count, arr[j] );       
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 instances of 1
2 instances of 2
1 instances of 3
1 instances of 4
1 instances of 7
3 instances of 9
```

If you want you may substitute this call of `printf`

```
printf( "%zu instances of %d\n", count, arr[j] );
```

for this one

```
if ( count != 1 ) printf( "%zu instances of %d\n", count, arr[j] );
```

In this case the output will be

```
2 instances of 2
3 instances of 9
```

**EDIT:** As for your solution published as an answer to your own question       then the code invokes undefined behavior due to accessing memory beyond the array in this expression `arr[i+1]` when `i` is equal to `NUM - 1`

```
for (i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
                  ^^^^^^^^  
        count++;
    }
    if (arr[i] != arr[i+1] && count>1) {
                  ^^^^^^^^
        printf("%d instances of %d\n", count, arr[i]);
        count=1;
    }
}
```